# For last 3 days I'm getting 404 from https://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all has the repo moved?

Tags: maven, redhat

The techpreview repository on redhat
https://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all returns 404
It prevents our pom dependencies from downloading

Comment: Use a repository manager and consume from central repository...

Comment: I just wanted to know if it is temporary situation before I change the url

Comment: I simply don't know if the redhat part is later back for usage but in general use a repository manager...and consume from central it's easier and more realiable.